# How to pass values to the parameters of the function of a javascript and get the result

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have a javascript function which is the formula for calculating the number of agents required for a call center. It accepts 5 values and returns one one value which is the number of agents required.
Can anyone please show an example for this javascript by passing few values to it and getting an output for this particular function. I want to use in jsp page.

### JS:

```
function Calculate( arrivalRate, callDuration, serviceLevelP, serviceLevelT, agentsCount ) {
    var rate = arrivalRate / 3600;
    var u = rate * callDuration;
    var sl = 0;
    var SL = serviceLevelP / 100;
    var m = Math.floor( u );
    var ummf = Math.pow( u, m ) / fact( m );
    var sm = 0;
    var ukkf = 1;
    for ( var i = 0;
    i < m;
    ++ i ) {
        ukkf = Math.pow( u, i ) / fact( i );
        sm += ukkf;
    }
    var tTs = serviceLevelT / callDuration;
    do {
        m ++;
        ummf *= u / m;
        ukkf *= u / ( m - 1 );
        sm += ukkf;
        var p = u / m;
        var E = ummf / ( ummf + ( 1 - p ) * sm );
        sl = 1 - E * Math.exp( ( u - m ) * tTs );
    }
    while ( sl < SL );
    agentsCount.SetValue( m );
    function fact( x ) {
        var ret = 1;
        for ( var i = 2;
        i <= x;
        ++ i ) {
            ret *= i;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: why does someone delete `java` tag?

Comment: What's to stop you passing values to it?

Comment: I don't know how to pass values to it and get the output.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko How is this question related to Java (as a programming language)? The function is in Javascript, the asker wants to use JSP for that. The `java` tag is IMHO superfluous.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek, `jsp` is a part of `javaee`

Answer (score 3):

A **very general** example - it is not clear **how** and **where** do you want get the values from:

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
...
<html>
  ...
  // somewhere in the <head> a <script> tag with your function
  ...
  <c:set var="jspArrivalRate" value="123" />
  <c:set var="jspCallDuration" value="456" />
  <c:set var="jspServiceLevelP" value="789" />
  <c:set var="jspServiceLevelT" value="1011" />
  <c:set var="jspAgentsCount" value="12" />
  ...
  <script>
    var result = Calculate(${jspArrivalRate}, ${jspCallDuration}, ${jspServiceLevelP}, ${jspServiceLevelT}, ${jspAgentsCount});
    // do whatever you want with the result
  </script>
  ...
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.I just want to know whether the formula in this function works properly or not. I made changes as you suggested,I think I messed up the page.If you don't mind can you tell me where to add the function in the html?Can you just edit the above code so that I can use it right away?